# C# How to Format a Number to a Hexicadecimal with a Prefix '0x'

Tags: c#, format, hex

How to Format a Number to a Hexicadecimal with a Prefix '0x'?

Such as:

```
int space = 32;
MessageBox.Show(space.ToString("'0x'X4")); // Output 0xX4 instead of 0x0020
```

I followed this link:
Custom Numeric Format Strings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx
Literal string delimiter: Indicates that the enclosed characters should be copied to the result string unchanged. 
But it does not work for 'X4' (it does work for '#'), kind of weird.

I'm using it in a DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Format, so I cannot use:

```
"0x{0:X4}", space
```

Thanks.
Peter

Comment: As I said, I'm using it in a DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Format, so I cannot use this.

Comment: Could you use custom formatting then? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Standard" formatting strings ("X4") are an *alternative* to the "Custom" formatting strings ("0000"), so you can't mix them.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715710/creating-a-custom-format-string-in-a-datagridview (they have a working solution).

Comment: Hi Gabe, I think you are right. That's why '#' works, but 'X' not, which is kind of sucking :-)  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom format string in a dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715710/creating-a-custom-format-string-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 6):

```
int space = 32;
MessageBox.Show("0x"+space.ToString("X"));
```

If you want to output `0x0020`:

```
MessageBox.Show("0x"+space.ToString("X4"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format("0x{0:x8}", ii);
```