# Minus sign on DataGridView on RTL language

Tags: c#, datagridview, right-to-left

Whenever I use a DataGridView negative values in it display the minus sign to the right of the number and not to the left: e.g.: 4.5- instead of -4.5. My DataGridview is set to "right to left" mode because the language is Hebrew.

How can I sort it out?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `DataGridView` Columns and `DataGridViewCellStyle`:

```
Format=#,##0.00;#,##0.00-, Alignment=MiddleCenter
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me for text entered to a Label using string.Format({0:0.##;0.##-}).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no luck with format strings (see [Creating a custom format string in a dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715710/creating-a-custom-format-string-in-a-datagridview)) have you tried explicitly rendering the numbers as strings and then displaying them?  I believe that might be the quickest and easiest answer.